# servidor "local" com python, não recebe um POST externo na mesma rede

Tags: python, c++, post, flask

Estou com um servidor rodando no PC com Windows 7 e estou usando a IDE PyCharm para editar e simular.
Este servidor está recebendo informações de um módulo ESP32 que está conectado na mesma rede do PC.
O envio do módulo ESP32 para o servidor:

```
Serial.println("========= Inicio post para servidor ==============");  
http.begin(client, Send_http_server(dia,temperatura, umidade, pressao, altitude, RPM, str_biruta, est_motor1, flag_motor1, pluviometro)); //HTTP
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");//inclui um cabeçalho da aplicação http 
int  httpCode = http.POST(Send_http_server(dia,temperatura, umidade, pressao, altitude, RPM, str_biruta, est_motor1, flag_motor1, pluviometro));
String payload = http.getString(); //Get the response payload
http.end();//finaliza a conexão alivia o sistema
Serial.print("Valor recebido do Rest httpCode:");
Serial.println(httpCode); //imprime o valor recebido do servidor
Serial.println("Play Load:" + payload); //Print request response payload
get_http(httpCode);  
Serial.println("========= Fim post para servidor ==============");
```

No servidor tenho:

```
    @app.route('/dados_esp32/<string:dados>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request(dados):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       bla.bla .bla....
```

Nos primeiros testes o envio ocorreu tudo certo, meu servidor recebeu e processou;
de uma hora para outra o servidor deixou de receber o `POST`.
Já tentei diversas coisas sem sucesso, mexi no firewall e mesmo assim não recebe o `POST`.

Porém quando envio uma solicitação do servidor para o módulo ESP32 eles se comunicam sem erro.
Para que o sistema funcione como pretendido, o módulo deve disparar envios para o servidor e não o contrário.

Incluindo mais informações:

[image: Tela do PC]

Comment: Tente imediatamente antes do `if request.method == 'POST'` colocar `print(request.method)` para confirmar qual o método está sendo recebido. Outra coisa é acrescentar todos os métodos no parâmetro `methods` do decorator. Outra coisa: como você está levantando o servidor Flask? Por fim, tente `netstat -an | find /i "listening"` para ver as portas abertas e escutando conexões.

Comment: Olá Paulo Marques, grato pela atenção! Tentei as alternativas indicas porem sem resultado ainda, Tentei criar uma regra para a porta 5000 no firewall, não consegui liberar o acesso.

Comment: [Não coloque cumprimentos e agradecimentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) na pergunta. Também não inclua assuntos alheios a TI, o sistema nos informa que é um novo usuário.

Comment: Analisando a pergunta, só tem um fragmento da mensagem de erro, é preciso a ver por completo para poder inicializar a análise do que leva o servidor a recusar a conexão. O que tem no arquivo de log *2021-03-04.txt*? Não publique [código ou log como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387)

Answer (score 3):

Você não está conseguindo receber um post externo porque não está fazendo o bind com o ip da máquina, `http://0.0.0.0:5000`.

A configuração deve ser feita na instância local do flask para setar um valor inicial para o parâmetro host da função run, por default quando este valor não é configurado é utilizado o valor `'127.0.0.1'`.

***app.py***

```
# python version 3.8.2
import os
from flask import json
from flask import Flask, render_template
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(_name_)
app.config['API_KEY'] = os.getenv("APIKEY")
    
# configurações de rotas

if _name_ == '_main_':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False) #<-- esta configuração deve ser feita, setar host='0.0.0.0'
```

Outra possibilidade é fazer a configuração via linha de comando ao servir as aplicações.

```
$ flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Informações sobre os parâmetros que podem ser utilizados em aplicações flask fazem parte do [quickstart do flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).

Comment: Ufa! parecia ser complicado... Danizavtz  meu sistem não suportou a instalação do dotenv, porem setar para `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)`; liberou a comunicação. Mas continuo com a duvida porque estava funcionando com `app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)` e parou de uma hora para outra???

Comment: O dotenv não é necessário, infelizmente eu também não sei porque funcionou em algum momento, de acordo com os logs que postou só vemos que não está funcionando, a única coisa que posso concluir é que talvez você tenha feito um post `'local'` por isso tenha funcionado.